# How do you prove that this infinite sum is just a power of a geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-distribution, geometric-series, negative-binomial

How do you prove that [the following series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkPaA.png) converges to $1/p^s$? 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+s-1}{s-1}(1-p)^k = (1-(1-p))^{-s} = p^{-s}$$
I got this from Iqbal Shahid's derivation of the expected value of the negative binomial distribution but he did not prove it.

Youtube: [Negative Binomial Distribution: Expected Value](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEZtLnulyg4)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $1-(1-p) = p$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan I don´t think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's another trick P Vanchinathan is getting at, but note that the Taylor coefficients of $(1-t)^{-s}$ are $a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=\frac{s\dots(s-(k-1))}{n!}$. Once you see where to go with this, you should then verify that the radius is exactly what you'd want it to be using the ratio test.

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate the method.

Comment: Anytime! Taylor's Theorem is the go-to approach for smooth functions.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that
$$ {k+s-1\choose s-1}=\frac{(k+s-1)!}{(s-1)!k!}=\frac{(k+s-1)\cdots (s+1)s}{k!}$$
$$=(-1)^k\frac{(-s)(-s-1)\cdots (-s-k+1)}{k!}=(-1)^k{-s\choose k}$$
(hence the name negative binomial distribution). Then by Newton's binomial theorem,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{k+s-1\choose s-1}(1-p)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{-s\choose k}(-1)^k(1-p)^k=(1-(1-p))^{-s}=p^{-s}$$

Comment: If $Re(s) > 1$, It converges only for [$|1-p| < 1$ or $p = 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence)

Comment: And a nice proof is there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Proof

Comment: @user1952009: $p$ is a probability, so...